# jQuery: Editing user inserted DOM elements

Tags: jquery, html, dom, button

I want to add html items (text and buttons inside a div) to the DOM and each item be editable or deletable.  I used jquery to do this as follows.

```
<div id="ak"></div>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="itext" size="60"/><br/>
<button id="but">Add Item</button>
<div id="test"></div>

$("#but").click(function(){
        var istring = $("#itext").val();
        $("#ak").append("<div class=\"item\"><p>"+istring+"<button class=\"editable\">Edit</button><button class=\"deletable\">Delete</button></p></div>");
        $("#itext").val("");
});

$(".deletable").click(function(){
    alert("Alert !!");   
});
```

However, when I pressed the delete button in each item nothing happens (should give an alert).  I feel something is very wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem a few days ago, but one of my coworkers was kind enough to clear up my confusion.

You need to rebind the click event after you add the HTML to the dom or use [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Some older versions of jQuery don't support live so you can use alternative means.

The following rebinds the click event after the HTML has been loaded:

```
$("#but").click(function(){
        var istring = $("#itext").val();
        $("#ak").append("<div class=\"item\"><p>"+istring+"<button class=\"editable\">Edit</button><button class=\"deletable\">Delete</button></p></div>");
        $("#itext").val("");
        clickEvent();
});
function clickEvent(){
    $(".deletable").click(function(){
        alert("Alert !!");   
    });
}
```

Or, using [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(".deletable").live('click',function(){
    alert("Alert !!");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) bcoz

> The **.live()** method is able to affect
>   elements that have not yet been added
>   to the DOM through the use of event
>   delegation:

```
$(".deletable").live('click',function(){
    alert("Alert !!");   
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/RqPLV/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that it's one of jQuery's shining gems, these event handlers on dynamically-created HTML elements. It's a perfectly valid topic, but I still wish we had, like, a quarter for everyone who asked why event handlers were not working on dynamically-created HTML elements. :D

And in every such question, I'd argue that you use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`, especially since (at least in your sample code) you **know** exactly from the get-go where you're inserting your elements.

```
$('#ak').delegate('.deletable', 'click', function (e) {
    // do something
});
```

No sense in going for `.live()` and popping up a global handler in a global context.

If you seriously don't want to go down the `live / delegate` path, you could always snap in your handlers as you're creating the element as well.

```
// creating a button with a click event handler
$('<button/>', {
    id : 'foo',
    class : 'deletable',
    click : function (e) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

... then you can use that and append that somewhere. You may find that this approach, when integrated in your code, might be more viable for you.